# Python "fileinput" module creates duplicate entry in PAM files

Tags: python, pam

I have below four PAM rules

```
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=0
auth [success=1 default=bad] pam_unix.so
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 unlock_time=0
auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 unlock_time=0`
```

to be added to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac` and `/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac` PAM files but with following conditions:

1) if the PAM entry is already available but with different `deny` or `unlock_time` value it has to be reset with the value `deny=5` and `unlock_time=0` accordingly;

2) if the PAM rule is not available at all in the entire file then that entry should be inserted above the first/starting `auth` rule entry in the file.

I have tried with the following code:

```
files = [
    "/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac",
    "/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac"
]
rules = [
    "auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 unlock_time=0",
    "auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 unlock_time=0",
    "auth [success=1 default=bad] pam_unix.so",
    "auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=0"
]
for file in files:
  for rule in rules:
     flag = 0
     regexrule = re.sub(r'([\[\]])', r'\\\1', rule)
     grepRule = re.sub(r'deny=5', 'deny=.*', regexrule)
     params = subprocess.Popen("egrep \'%s\' %s"%(regexrule, file), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].split("\n")
     if len(params) == 1:
        for pamd in fileinput.FileInput(file, 'inplace=1'):
            if re.match(r'auth\s+required\s+pam_tally2.so', pamd):
               continue
            if re.match(grepRule, pamd) and not flag:
               pamd = rule
               flag = 1
            elif pamd.startswith("auth") and not flag:
               pamd = rule + "\n" + pamd
               flag = 1
            print pamd.strip()
```

It inserts duplicate PAM entries when any of the parameter value is different other than the one I specified (instead of replacing the values).

Also the above code is a mess and I want to get an elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: I know it is off-topic but that looks like a perfect task for Ansible's [```pamd```](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/pamd_module.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using below ways:

Method-1:

```
  for file in files:
      for rule in rules:
         flag = 0
         regexrule= re.sub(r'([\[\]])',r'\\\1',rule)
         grepRule = re.sub(r'unlock_time=[0-9]*', 'unlock_time=.*',regexrule)
         grepRule = re.sub(r'deny=[0-9]*', 'deny=.*', grepRule)
         params = subprocess.Popen("egrep \'%s\' %s"%(grepRule,file),stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True).communicate()[0].split("\n")
         if len(params) == 1:
            for pamd in fileinput.FileInput(file,'inplace=1'):
                if re.match(r'auth\s+required\s+pam_tally2.so',pamd):
                   continue
                if re.match(grepRule,pamd) and not flag:
                   pamd = rule
                   flag = 1
                elif pamd.startswith("auth") and not flag:
                   pamd = rule + "\n" + pamd
                   flag = 1
                print pamd.strip()
         elif len(params) == 2:
             for pamd in fileinput.FileInput(file,'inplace=1'):
                 if re.match(grepRule,pamd) and not flag:
                     pamd =  rule
                 print pamd.strip()
```

Method-2:

```
for rule in rules:
    flag = 0
    grepRule = re.sub(r'([\[\]])',r'\\\1', rule)
    grepRule = re.sub(r'deny=\d+', 'deny=.*', grepRule)
    grepRule = re.sub(r'unlock_time=\d+', 'unlock_time=.*', grepRule)
    for pamd in fileinput.FileInput(files=("/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac"), inplace=1):
        if re.match(grepRule, pamd.strip()):
            flag = 1
        sys.stdout.write(re.sub(grepRule, rule, pamd))
    else:
        if not flag:
            for pamd in fileinput.FileInput(files=("/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac"), inplace=1):
                if pamd.startswith("auth") and not flag:
                    pamd = rule + "\n" + pamd
                    flag = 1
                print pamd.strip()
```

However, the second method works for only one file in case when the specified rules are not found in the file. For any improvement points to the above code are most welcome.